# What is the modern simple way to pass data from one page to another using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I need to pass data from one HTML(`source.html`) to another HTML(`destination.html`) and assign this passed data to `value` attribute in `<input>` tag at the `destination.html` page using modern javascript techniques.

Here is my `function` @ `source.html`.

```
function sentData(){
  var send = "Send Me"
  }
```

Here is my `<input>` tag @ `destination.html`.

```
<input id="sendedData" type="Text" value="send">
```

What is the best modern simply way to do this? your advice would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

In the first page store the item as

```
localStorage.setItem('keyName','valueInString');
```

In the second page retrieve the value

```
if(localStorage.getItem('keyName')){
 document.getElementById('sendedData').value = localStorage.getItem('keyName')

}
```

Comment: For this purpose, I'd prefer [Session Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage) instead.

Answer (score 0):

The best way same as the old on is a form with submit() if you don't want to ask for an input like you post, you can hide the input  and a  as your trigger.

If you need to use JS for some reason brk answear is the best one.
basicly you name the page and then you tell them to update a label or an input on that specific page.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `localStorage` like so:

`source.html`:

```
function sentData() {
    var data = "Send Me";
    localStorage.setItem("data", data);
}
```

`destination.html`:

```
document.getElementById("sendedData").value = localStorage.getItem("data") ? localStorage.getItem("data") : "Default";
```

Alternatively, use a URL parameter / query string:

`source.html`:

```
function sendData() {
    var data = "Send Me";
    var url = new URL(window.location.href);
    url.searchParams.set("data", data);
}
```

`destination.html`:

```
var url = new URL(window.location.href);
document.getElementById("sendedData").value = url.searchParams.get("data") ? url.searchParams.get("data") : "Default";
```